# python pip install scipy error

Tags: python, linux, scipy, pip

**Getting error with pip install scipy,all depends have been installed.Can anyone tell me what is going on.** the os :Linux iZ25qaqvf80Z 2.6.32-220.23.2.al.ali1.1.alios6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 4 15:01:53 CST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
    >>pip install scipy
    Collecting scipy
      Using cached scipy-0.16.0.tar.gz
    Installing collected packages: scipy
      Running setup.py install for scipy

    ....
    ....
    ....

    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/sparse/sparsetools
    compile options: '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iscipy/sparse/sparsetools -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c'
    g++: scipy/sparse/sparsetools/sparsetools.cxx
    In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/sparsetools.cxx:34:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
    g++: scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.cxx
    In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/sparsetools.h:5,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.cxx:4:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
    g++: scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.cxx
    In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/sparsetools.h:5,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.cxx:4:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
    g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See <http://bbs.aliyun.com> for instructions.
    In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/sparsetools.h:5,
                     from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.cxx:4:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
    g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See <http://bbs.aliyun.com> for instructions.
    error: Command "g++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iscipy/sparse/sparsetools -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.o" failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-CO2sfG/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-LWP6FE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-CO2sfG/scipy
```

Comment: bbs.aliyun.com? isn't g++ maintained by https://gcc.gnu.org ? Possible spam?

Comment: gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (AliCloud Linux 4.4.6-3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: is your problem solved when running with root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can `sudo apt-get install python-scipy`, I came across the the same problem today.

Answer (score 0):

try using `sudo pip install scipy`

Comment: execue "pip install scipy" with root

Answer (score 0):

**Solved this problem by create 1G swap zone ,thanks .**